# Interval Problems

Tags: real-analysis

http://s24.postimg.org/yasuyp1cl/real_analysis.jpg

I try to solve these two exercises. I have found that the intervals are $$(0,\frac{1}{n}) \quad for \quad the \quad first \quad case \quad and \quad (\frac{-1}{n},\frac{1}{n}) \quad for \quad the \quad second \quad case$$

I want help, however, to prove that these two intervals have the stated property. Can anyone help?

Comment: For the first, given $x>0$, choose an integer $N$ with $x>1/N$. Then $x\notin A_N$.  Something similar will work for your second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, if there exists $x\in(0,1)$ such that $x\in\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$, then you will have a contradiction as there exists $N$ such that $x\notin(0,\frac{1}{N})$.

Then second one is similar.